# Combining SQL queries without JOIN or UNION

Tags: sql

I need to count rows in two tables, and I would like to make a single SQL-query do the job. After some research I found an solution which I modified to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(activate_account.id), COUNT(members.id) FROM members, activate_account 
WHERE members.email = :email or activate_account.email = :email
```

Now my question is: is this a good way to combine two SELECT queries, is this just as good solution as if I would have used JOIN or UNION (meaning should there be any peformance improvement compared to if I would have two separate SELECT queries)?

Answer (score 3):

It might be late reply but below will work

```
SELECT tblactivate_account.activate_account, tblmembers.members
FROM 
( SELECT COUNT(activate_account.id) activate_account 
WHERE activate_account.email = email ) tblactivate_account,
( SELECT COUNT(members.id) members FROM members
WHERE members.email = email ) tblmembers
```

modification for nrathaus answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two separate queries and join their result not JOIN their tables.

Some pseudo untested SQL but should work:

```
SELECT tblactivate_account.activate_account, tblmembers.members
FROM 
( SELECT COUNT(activate_account.id) activate_account 
  WHERE activate_account.email = :email ) AS tblactivate_account,
( SELECT COUNT(members.id) FROM members
  WHERE members.email = :email ) AS tblmembers
```

Answer (score 1):

JOIN and UNION are differents.

In your query you have used a CROSS JOIN operation, because when you use a comma between two table you apply a CROSS JOIN. It becomes INNER JOIN if you in your WHERE clause put a link between two table, in your case members and activate_account aren't linked.

UNION can be used when you want get values from two distinct sets. i.e. if you want a list of employees and a list of sailors, supposed, employees and sailors are in two different table.

Answer (score 0):

> meaning should there be any peformance improvement compared to if I
> would have two separate SELECT queries

Well there is no good reason why you are avoiding the JOINS and UNION if you want to combine two tables. As far as performance issue is concerned I dont think that using JOINS will lead you to any such trouble. Also to mention that UNION puts lines from queries after each other, while JOIN makes a cartesian product and subsets it which is a completely different operations.

BTW you may also like to read about : [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) as I suspect that you are using the older convention to join tables.